# org.json.JSONExeption: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android

I'm trying to create an app that involves login. But I getting a problem in the registration.

I tried change the php but I get the same mensagem.

```java
private void registerUser() {
        displayLoader();
        JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
        try {
            request.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
            request.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
            request.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest jsArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.POST, register_url, request, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            if (response.getInt(KEY_STATUS) == 0) {
                                session.loginUser(username,email);
                                loadDashboard();

                            }else if(response.getInt(KEY_STATUS) == 1){
                                etUsername.setError("Usuario já usado");
                                etUsername.requestFocus();

                            }else if(response.getInt(KEY_STATUS) == 3){
                                etEmail.setError("Email já usado");
                                etEmail.requestFocus();
                            } else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        response.getString(KEY_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsArrayRequest);
    }
```

```java
public class MySingleton {

    private static MySingleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private MySingleton(Context context) {

        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {

        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
        }

        return mInstance;

    }

    private RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {

        if (mRequestQueue == null) {

            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {

        getRequestQueue().add(req);

    }

}
```

```php
<?php

    $response = array();
    include 'conectar_db.php';
    include 'funcoes.php';

    $inputJSON = file_get_contents('http://teste-app-lhama.epizy.com/controle/registrar.php');
    $input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE);

    if(isset($input['username']) && isset($input['password']) && isset($input['email'])){

        $username = $input['username'];
        $password = $input['password'];
        $password = hashPass($password);
        $email = $input['email'];

        if(!userExists($username)){

            if(!emailExists($email)){
                $salt = getSalt();

                $passwordHash = password_hash(concatPasswordWithSalt($password,$salt),PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                $insertQuery  = "INSERT INTO Informacoes(username, email, password_hash, salt) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

                if($stmt = $con->prepare($insertQuery)){

                    $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$username,$email,$passwordHash,$salt);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $response["status"] = 0;
                    $response["message"] = "Usuario criado com sucesso";
                    $stmt->close();

                }
            }

            else{

                $response["status"] = 3;
                $response["message"] = "Email j? existe";

            }

        }

        else{

            $response["status"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Usuario j? existe";

        }

    }

    else{

        $response["status"] = 2;
        $response["message"] = "Falta de parametro obrigatorios";

    }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

```php
function userExists($username){

        $query = "SELECT username FROM Informacoes WHERE username = ?";

        global $con;

        if($stmt = $con->prepare($query)){
            $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->fetch();
            if($stmt->num_rows == 1){
                $stmt->close();
                echo "Usuario existente";
                return true;
            }

            $stmt->close();

        }

        return false;
    }

function emailExists($email){

        $query = "SELECT email FROM Informacoes WHERE email = ?";

        global $con;

        if($stmt = $con->prepare($query)){
            $stmt->bind_param("s",$email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->fetch();
            if($stmt->num_rows == 1){
                $stmt->close();
                echo "Email existente";
                return true;
            }

            $stmt->close();

        }

        return false;
    }
```

The log.

```java
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa24b0920: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa4e099a0)
I/chatty: uid=10091(com.lhamaintergalatica.controlefinaceiro) RenderThread identical 6 lines
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa24b0920: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa4e099a0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa24b0920: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa4e099a0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa24b0920: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa4e099a0)
```

The odd thing is, when I put the url: "http://teste-app-lhama.epizy.com/controle/registrar.php" in the browser I get this result:"{"status":2,"message":"Falta de parametro obrigatorios"(missing mandatory params)}"
Probably the result is return the right value, right?

I believe the problem is in my php inside this if "if(isset($input['username']) && isset($input['password']) && isset($input['email']))"

I was reading in the internet, and I found someone say that this error could be caused by the host. If that is true, what i should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is here:

```php
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('http://teste-app-lhama.epizy.com/controle/registrar.php');
```

should be:

```php
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Answer (score 1):

do not forget to set header content type to json , so response consider as json not string :) :

```
<?PHP
$data = /** whatever you're serializing **/;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

do not do this :

```
echo "Email existente";
```

it is string , not json.